# Sampling from a prior (using delta); While loop

Tags: python, while-loop, sampling

I am attempting do MCMC with 'a' as one of the parameters. The proposed value of 'a' is obtained randomly from a uniform distribution (a-delta, a+delta) as long as the pdf of the proposed value of a is not zero. Here's a test of the code I wrote.

```
from scipy.stats import uniform
import numpy as np

prior_a= uniform(1,79)
delta = 5

a_current = 40
all_a = []
for i in range(1,1000):
    a_proposal = np.random.uniform(a_current-delta, a_current+delta)
    while prior_a.pdf(a_proposal)<0:
        a_proposal = np.random.uniform(a_current-delta, a_current+delta)
    a_current = a_proposal
    all_a.append(a_current)

print(max(all_a))
print(min(all_a))
```

In principle, the maximum value of a_current should not be >80 or less than 1 (because a.pdf(x) where x is less than 1 or more than 80 would be 0). But when I run this code several times, I frequently gets a value that's either more than 80 or less than 1.

I am not sure what's wrong.

Comment: Read https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/ for tips on debugging your code.

Comment: Got it; it should have been "while prior_a.pdf(a_proposal) == 0" instead of '<0'.